# Can't make LVM Cache to be persistent after system reboot

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, raid, cache, lvm

I've got LVM logical volume on top of MDADM RAID1 setup. I'm trying to add SSD device as Cache to this logical volume via:

```
vgextend dataVG /dev/sdd
lvcreate --type cache --cachemode writethrough -L 120G -n dataLV_cachepool dataVG/dataLV /dev/sdd
```

All seems to be fine until I reboot my system. After the reboot it fail to start and I get recovery mode (Ubuntu).

I see the following errors during the boot process:

```
lvm[740]:   dataVG: autoactivation failed.
systemd[1]: lvm2-pvscan@9:2.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=5/NOTINSTALLED
systemd[1]: lvm2-pvscan@9:2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start LVM2 PV scan on device 9:2.
lvm[774]:   /usr/sbin/cache_check: execvp failed: No such file or directory
lvm[774]:   Check of pool dataVG/dataLV_cachepool failed (status:2). Manual repair required!
lvm[774]:   0 logical volume(s) in volume group "dataVG" now active
lvm[774]:   dataVG: autoactivation failed.
systemd[1]: Started File System Check on /dev/mapper/BACKUPVG-mainbackup.
systemd[1]: lvm2-pvscan@8:16.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=5/NOTINSTALLED
systemd[1]: lvm2-pvscan@8:16.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start LVM2 PV scan on device 8:16.
systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/mainbackup...
systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt/mainbackup.
kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
systemd[1]: dev-mapper-dataVG\x2dataLV.device: Job dev-mapper-dataVG\x2dataLV.device/start timed out.
systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-mapper-dataVG\x2dataLV.device.
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/dataLV.
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
systemd[1]: mnt-dataLV.mount: Job mnt-dataLV.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/mapper/dataVG-dataLV.
systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-dataVG\x2dataLV.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-dataVG\x2dataLV.service/start failed with resu
systemd[1]: dev-mapper-dataVG\x2dataLV.device: Job dev-mapper-dataVG\x2dataLV.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

It works only when I remove cached drive from the VG:

```
lvconvert --uncache dataVG/dataLV
```

Not sure how to approach this issue...

**LVM version**:

```
LVM version:     2.02.176(2) (2017-11-03)
Library version: 1.02.145 (2017-11-03)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue on Debian 8. Resolution consists of two steps.

First, because required modules are not loaded during boot, the systems results in booted with inactive state LVMs for cached LVs.

Trying to activate them manually, result in error:

```
vgchange -a y vg0/home_cache
   /usr/sbin/cache_check: execvp failed: No such file or directory
   Check of pool vg0/home_cache failed (status:2). Manual repair required!
```

Indeed, the command /usr/sbin/cache_check doesn't exist. Fix it by installing:

```
apt-get install thin-provisioning-tools
```

Second, fix the problem, which is cause why LVM cache volumes are not activated. 
There are few modules required to be present in initramfs boot image. Add them to forced modules for include:

```
sudo echo "dm_cache" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
sudo echo "dm_cache_mq" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
sudo echo "dm_persistent_data" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
sudo echo "dm_bufio" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```

And after this do:

```
update-initramfs -k `uname -r` -u -t
```

and finally secure your self by:

```
update-grub
```

Check everything twice, and finally reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need cache kernel module (dm-cache) and /usr/sbin/cache_* tools in your init ramdisk. In fedora it is handled by dracut, in debian (and ubuntu) initramfs-tools package.

Comment: unfortunately adding dm-cache (`modprobe dm-cache`) and installing the required package didn't help. Also it looks like my folder `/usr/sbin/` is missing cache_* tools.

Comment: Do you have thin-provisioning-tools installed?

Comment: looks like it is installed. I've tried to re-install it and add the cache drive to my existing LVM configuration. Unfortunately, this failed with the same error